# запрос в wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

как правильно сформировать запрос в wordpress?

уменя есть рубрика r1 в которой ещо две рубрики subr1 subr2
в етих subr1 subr2 есть пости
как сформировать 1 запрос чтоби получить имена рубрик і імена постов с их содержимим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT WP.`name`, `posts`.`post_title`, `posts`.`post_content`  
FROM `terms` as WP
INNER JOIN `term_relationships` ON WP.`term_id`= 
`term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id`
INNER JOIN  `posts` ON `term_relationships`.`object_id` = `posts`.`ID`
WHERE WP.`term_id` IN (SELECT `term_taxonomy`.`term_id`
FROM `terms`
INNER JOIN `term_taxonomy` ON `wp_terms`.`term_id`=`term_taxonomy`.term_id 
OR `terms`.`term_id`=`term_taxonomy`.parent
where `terms`.`name`='r1')
```